# Catalina Terminal prompt customise

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I have update my mac book pro 2017 15 inches to catalina. I wanted to customize my terminal window default prompt some thing like this
**`Praveen > Training > Java >`**
Where Praveen is the user name, Java is the sub folder under Training folder. I did this in Mojave . But I am not able to do in Catalina. Request you to help me to change my terminal prompt like that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apple switched the default shell from bash to zsh. If your old prompt is written for bash, it will not work in zsh. zsh provide more rich functionality then batch. You can check this link to learn more about that.

https://www.howtogeek.com/362409/what-is-zsh-and-why-should-you-use-it-instead-of-bash/

If you are using zsh, I suggest you try theme p10k. It is highly configurable and it is really fast. I am pretty sure it will satisfy your needs.

https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k